# jQuery .post() scrolls to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, scroll

I have a button `<a href="#" onClick="buy(id)">Buy</a>`

The `buy` function uses `$.post()` function to process the request and return an updated shopping cart bar, and also updates the div with the cart bar that is on the top of the page. And then it scrolls up to top, but I don't want it to scroll up. How can I fix this? The `buy` function returns `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$('#element').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //do whatever
});
```

Comment: right, you should avoid inline scripts and maybe have a working href

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass `return false;`:

```
<a href="#" onClick="buy(id); return false;">Buy</a>
```

another option is to give an id or class name and in the callback stop the default behavior.

```
<a href="#" id='buyBtn'>Buy</a>
```

then jQuery event:

```
$('#buyBtn').on('click', function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     buy(id);
});
```

Comment: Just to point it out. `return false` also stops the click propagation, which might not be ideal in all cases.

Comment: yes you are correct! `return false;` stops both or you can say do two things stops execution and event to bubble up.